# compare two date in javascript/jquery using day accuracy

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, compare

I need to compare two dates using best accuracy, for me day will be ok and take into consideration leap years.

It is possible ? I for now only create function to compare month accurancy :/

Answer (score 2):

If you have date strings, you can parse them by using `Date.parse("datestring")`. It will return long(time in milliseconds). And you can compare any two longs.

```
var date1 = new Date("10/25/2011");
var date2 = new Date("09/03/2010");
var date3 = new Date(Date.parse(date1) - Date.parse(date2));

var dayDiff = date3.getDate() - 1;
var monthDiff = date3.getMonth();
var yearDiff = date3.getFullYear() - 1970;
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JmYCN/25/) to test it.

Comment: Will this miliseconds consider leap years ? How can I convert miliseconds to days ? I have birth date and drive license date and I want to calculate that person have 17 years when pass license...

Comment: I've edited my answer with some piece of code. You can test it.

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract Date object from another Date object and return microseconds

```
var d= new Date('2012/11/29');
var a= new Date('2012/11/30');
alert( (a-d) /(1000*24*60*60)) ); /* returns 1 */
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for difference in days with fairly good precision:

```
function daysSince( past ) {
  return 0|( new Date().getTime() - past.getTime() ) * 1.16e-8;
}

console.log( daysSince( new Date('10/03/2012') ) ); //=> 31
```

**Edit:** Actually, if you only want to know the difference between two dates you can always return a positive number.

```
function daysBetweenDates( d1,d2 ) {
  return Math.abs( 0|( d1.getTime() - d2.getTime() ) * 1.16e-8 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best JavaScript Time and Date manipulation library I've come across is [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Getting the # of days between two dates:

```
d1 = moment('2012-10-31')
d2 = moment('2012-11-02')
Math.abs(moment.duration(d1-d2, 'ms').days())
// => 2
```

The default precision is milliseconds.

Comment: @KKyle Burton have always used date.js which has been around a long time. Really like moment.js docs!

Comment: dayjs is much more lightweight than momentjs